# Nhibernate: Get real entity class instead of proxied class

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way to make nhibernate return my class instead of its proxy class? I dont mind if it's not lazy or cant be updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can unproxy class with this code

```
session.PersistenceContext.Unproxy(proxiedInstance)
```

Comment: Is there a way to unproxy all associations as well? It unproxies my main object but its relations to other object keep proxied.

Answer (score 2):

You should define this in your mapping, by defining lazy="false"

```
<class name="MyEntity" table="MyTable" lazy="false">
</class>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to get real object

```
InstanceType instance;
if (proxiedInstance is INHibernateProxy)
{
 var lazyInitialiser = ((INHibernateProxy)proxiedInstance).HibernateLazyInitializer;
 instance = (InstanceType)lazyInitialiser.GetImplementation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to achieve something similar in Entity Framework.

```
var nonProxiedInstance = Mapper.DynamicMap<YourType>(proxiedInstance);
```

That would work if you do not have navigation properties. Otherwise, you'll need to configure a mapping to ignore those properties.

Note: This is (obviously) an inefficient solution.

Comment: This doesn't work. The proxy doesn't contain the properties of the inherited (real) class, so it would be missing in the mapped type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the technique described in http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html (you'll need to do it recursively)

Answer (score 0):

`session.PersistenceContext.Unproxy(proxiedInstance)` will not unproxy the associations. Also the `no-proxy` lazy loading does the same thing.
Disabling lazy loading is not a good idea and AutoMapper would navigate all the properties and trigger the loading mechanism.

[`IUnitOfWork.Unproxy`](https://github.com/CSharpBender/NHUnit/blob/master/src/NHUnit/Interfaces/IUnitOfWork.cs#L71) from the [NHUnit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHUnit/) could be used to unproxy the object and it's relations. This method will not initialize any proxy objects by mistake.

Comment: What specifically is "none of the above"? That comment doesn't work when people submit in new answers. You should specify what techniques won't work and why.